# python- plot heatmap at given coordinates using basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I am trying to make a map in basemap using pcolormesh (and I'm open to other methods). I have a csv file with coordinates, and one with the corresponding density value. (Should they be in one file?) I am trying to load the values as a numpy array and then plot the map, but I am unsure as how to correspond the density to the point. My map is currently just displaying blue everywhere, so I think it is just counting each coordinate and displaying it. NOTE: In the example code below, I created a CSV that has the coordinates and the density, for ease of testing.

Ideally, I have a range of values in density and the lower will be blue and the higher will be red. I am just very confused by how to put the density in there.

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

m = Basemap(projection='npstere',boundinglat=60,lon_0=270,resolution='l')
m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawcounties()

array = np.genfromtxt("fake.csv", delimiter=",", skip_header=1)

lats = array[0,:]
lons = array[1,:]

nx = 360
ny = 180

lon_bins = np.linspace(-180, 180, nx)
lat_bins = np.linspace(70, 90, ny)

density, lat_edges, lon_edges = np.histogram2d(lats, lons, [lat_bins, lon_bins])

lon_bins_2d, lat_bins_2d = np.meshgrid(lon_bins, lat_bins)

xs, ys = m(lon_bins_2d, lat_bins_2d)

density = np.hstack((density, np.zeros((density.shape[0], 1))))
density = np.vstack((density, np.zeros((density.shape[1]))))

plt.pcolormesh(xs, ys, density, cmap="jet", shading='gouraud')

plt.show()
```

Admittedly, some of this code is patched together from googling for help, and this currently produces my desired map but, instead of displaying density, it's just a big blue blob. How do I get the density value to correspond to each coordinate? Thanks!